# Do while loop is not repeating

Tags: java, chatbot

I want it to ask the user for an input again if he misspells "im sad" and go through the whole switch process.

When I type "imsed" it says "I don't understand" as it's supposed to and asks for another input but when I type in the other input, it just ends.

I can't use arrays yet.

```
do {
    if (a.contains("sad")) {
        System.out.println("bot: " + "Hey there! Dont be sad, Here is a pun to cheer you up");
        System.out.println();
        i = 1 + dice.nextInt(3);
        switch (i) { // start of switch 

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Why did the traffic light felt embarrased?\n" 
                    + "Because everyone saw it changing");
                a = input.nextLine();
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Why was Cinderella thrown off the basketball team?"
                    + "\nShe ran away from the ball.");
                a = input.nextLine();
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Why is Peter Pan always flying?\n"
                    + "He neverlands.");
                a = input.nextLine();
                break;
        } //end of  switch
    } else if (a.contains("again")) {
        e = 1 + dice.nextInt(3);
        switch (e) { // start of switch 

            case 1:
                System.out.println("How do you know it's an emotional wedding?\n" + "When the cake is in tiers");
                a = input.nextLine();
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("What does a house wear?" + "\nA Dress.");
                a = input.nextLine();
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("How do you know a frenchmen plays video games?\n" + "He says wii when you ask him.");
                a = input.nextLine();
                break;
        } //end of  switch
    }
} while (a.equals("again")


if (a.contains("im happy")) {
    System.out.println("bot: " + "Have a great day ahead!");
}
if (!a.equals("im sad")
    || !a.equals("im happy"
    || !a.equals("again")) {
    System.out.println("bot: " + "I don't understand");
    a = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Where's the while for the do?

Comment: whoops i must've deleted it accidentally. there it is @Carcigenicate

Comment: Don't the if statements at the bottom need to be in the loop? Why would you expect it to loop back if they aren't even in the loop?

Comment: Also, you have misplaced brackets all over the place. You should fix those first. Missing end parentheses at `while (a.equals("again")` and `!a.equals("im happy"`.

Comment: thank you very much @Carcigenicate i fixed it already